# Trouble making css :last-child work for me

Tags: html, css

Obviously I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what's wrong with this, it's driving me crazy.

The selector I'd LIKE to use is: `.menu ul li:last-child > a`

The 'unique selector' that firefox gives me is `.menu > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(5) > a:nth-child(1)`

the HTML is:

```
<div class='menu'>
    <ul><li><a href=''>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='1'>Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='2'>Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='3'>Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='4'>Link 4</a></li>
    <ul>
 </div>
```

How is `li:last-child > a` not selecting 'Link 4'? I am really quite confused, so thanks in advance for the upcoming lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, your closing `ul` tag is wrong.

```
<div class='menu'>
    <ul><li><a href=''>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='1'>Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='2'>Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='3'>Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='4'>Link 4</a></li>
    </ul> //change this
 </div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dLMs/)

Comment: Hah! Wow! That was a nice typo. Thanks :) I knew it was something dumb that I was missing.